# My block call to get products from category dont work

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, cms

My client wants to display some product groups on his frontpage. 
So i used the code i used on every other magento site i have worked on. But on this it does not work.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: does it work if you switch to the default theme?

Comment: no :( Just tried

Comment: Can you determine if the template is being called? This will at least tell you the block is actioned, and if the issue is that no products are found to list.

Comment: r u using magento version 1.9.2.2?

Comment: I´m not sure if its important but ' name="WHATEVERYOUCALLIT" ' is missing

Comment: Yeah its magento 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add block in `white list`

1. Login to admin panel then go to System > Permissions > Blocks
2. Add the block - Enter `catalog/product_list` in the field
3. Set Allowed to Yes

Comment: Nice that did it! Thx

Comment: Man, that got me just the other day.....and i already forgot about that whitelist by today!